# Google Traffic and CDN

Tags: image, seo, cdn, traffic

I have moved all images from a website to a content delivery network on another domain. And, as a result, lost all Google image search traffic. Is damage permanent or will traffic return, will images on another domain still allow my site to be in image search results? Maybe I should have moved images gradually? Any advise?

Comment: Wow, I'm experiencing the same problem. I own a blog and I've lost all my google images traffic since I moved them to CDN.  Anyone found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, I restored the previous links and redirected traffic permanently with .htaccess to the CDN.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. If someone has directed you here to read this warning, go back and delete your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's gone because Google can now no longer find the images it had previously spidered, google will of course find the new locations however there is no guarantee it will rank your images the same as before.

The best way to recover is to implement 301 redirects using your .htaccess file. Depending on how you've moved the images and if they are in the same or a different folder structure it may require a bit of work to fix.

Comment: So, I basically put back the old URLs but redirect them to the CDN?